# Gulp AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified

Tags: angularjs, gulp, assertion

I'm trying to customize a template for a demo of a webapp built on **AngularJS** using **MacOS Sierra 10.13.6**. I've installed **Gulp** but when I launch `gulp serve` return this error without launching the local server:

> assert.js:337 throw err; ^
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified at
>   Gulp.set [as _setTask]
>   (/Users/barkia/Desktop/Elysium/repos/elysium-webapp/material/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
>   at Gulp.task
>   (/Users/barkia/Desktop/Elysium/repos/elysium-webapp/material/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
>   at Object.
>   (/Users/barkia/Desktop/Elysium/repos/elysium-webapp/material/gulpfile.js:9:6)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) at
>   tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3) at
>   Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17) at require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)

Here is the gulpfile.js actually in `~/Desktop/Elysium/repos/elysium-webapp/material/gulpfile.js`

I've deleted the previous error regarding `/usr/local/share/man/man1/gulp.1` by launching `npm uninstall -g gulp` and after `npm install -g gulp` but I still have that issues on `assert.js:337`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
var del = require('del');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true});

gulp.task('help', $.taskListing);
gulp.task('default', ['help']);

gulp.task('vet', function() {
    log('Analyzing source with JSHint and JSCS');

    return gulp
        .src(config.alljs)
        .pipe($.if(args.verbose, $.print()))
        .pipe($.jscs())
        .pipe($.jshint())
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', {verbose: true}))
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('fail'));
});

gulp.task('clean-tmp', function(done) {
    var files = config.tmp;
    clean(files, done);
});

gulp.task('clean', function(done) {
    var delconfig = [].concat(config.dist, config.tmp);
    log('Cleaning ' + $.util.colors.blue(delconfig));
    del(delconfig, done);
});

gulp.task('clean-all', function(done) {
    var delconfig = config.allToClean;
    log('Cleaning ' + $.util.colors.blue(delconfig));
    clean(delconfig, done);
});

gulp.task('pug-docs', function() {
    log('Compiling docs pug --> html');

    var options = {
        pretty: false
    }

    return gulp
        .src(config.docsPug)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: swallowError}))
        .pipe($.pug(options))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.docs));
});

gulp.task('less', function() {
    log('Compiling Less --> CSS');

    return gulp
        .src(config.less)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: swallowError}))
        .pipe($.less())
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('less-watcher', function() {
    gulp.watch([config.less], ['less']);
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    log('Compiling Sass --> CSS');

    var sassOptions = {
        outputStyle: 'nested' // nested, expanded, compact, compressed
    };

    return gulp
        .src(config.sass)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: swallowError}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.sass(sassOptions))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp + '/styles'));
});

gulp.task('sass-min', function() {
    log('Compiling Sass --> minified CSS');

    var sassOptions = {
        outputStyle: 'compressed' // nested, expanded, compact, compressed
    };

    return gulp
        .src(config.sass)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: swallowError}))
        .pipe($.sass(sassOptions))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp + '/styles'));    
})

gulp.task('sass-watcher', function() {
    gulp.watch([config.sass], ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('inject', function() {
    log('Injecting custom scripts to index.html');

    return gulp
        .src(config.index)
        .pipe( $.inject(gulp.src(config.js), {relative: true}) )
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client));
});

gulp.task('copy', ['sass-min'], function() {
    log('Copying assets');

    var assets = [].concat(config.assetsLazyLoad, config.assetsToCopy);

    gulp.src(config.tmp + '/styles/loader.css').pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + '/styles'));

    return gulp
        .src(assets, {base: config.client})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + '/'));
});

gulp.task('optimize', ['inject', 'sass-min'], function() {
    log('Optimizing the js, css, html');

    return gulp
        .src(config.index)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: swallowError}))
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe($.if('scripts/app.js', $.uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( config.dist ));

});


gulp.task('serve', ['inject', 'sass'], function() {
    startBrowserSync('serve');
});

gulp.task('build', ['optimize', 'copy'], function() {
    startBrowserSync('dist');
})

gulp.task('serve-dist', function() {
    gulp.run('build');
})

gulp.task('serve-docs', ['pug-docs'], function() {
    startBrowserSync('docs');
})



function clean(path, done) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));
    del(path, done);
}

function log(msg) {
    if (typeof(msg) === 'object') {
        for (var item in msg) {
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                $.util.log($.util.colors.green(msg[item]));
            }
        }
    } else {
        $.util.log($.util.colors.green(msg));
    }
}

function swallowError (error) {
    // If you want details of the error in the console
    console.log(error.toString());

    this.emit('end');
}

function startBrowserSync(opt) {
    if (args.nosync || browserSync.active) {
        return;
    }

    var options = {
        port: 3000,
        ghostMode: {
            clicks: false,
            location: false,
            forms: false,
            scroll: true
        },
        injectChanges: true,
        logFileChanges: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        logPrefix: 'gulp-patterns',
        notify: true,
        reloadDelay: 0, //1000,
        online: false
    };

    switch(opt) {
        case 'dist':
            log('Serving dist app');
            serveDistApp();
            break;
        case 'docs':
            log('Serving docs');
            serveDocs();
            break;
        default:
            log('Serving app');
            serveApp();
            break;
    }

    function serveApp() {
        gulp.watch([config.sass], ['sass']);

        options.server = {
            baseDir: [
                config.client,
                config.tmp
            ]
        };
        options.files = [
            config.client + '/**/*.*',
            '!' + config.sass,
            config.tmp + '/**/*.css'
        ];

        browserSync(options);
    }

    function serveDistApp() {
        options.server = {
            baseDir: [
                config.dist
            ]
        };
        options.files = [];

        browserSync(options);
    }

    function serveDocs() {
        gulp.watch([config.docsPug], ['pug-docs']);

        options.server = {
            baseDir: [
                config.docs
            ]
        }

        options.files = [
            config.docs + '/index.html',
            '!' + config.pug
        ];

        browserSync(options);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 56):

I just run into the same problem while upgrading to gulp 4.

The depending tasks have to be specified as series or in parallel, just the name is not enough anymore.

Example

```
gulp.task('copy', ['sass-min'], function() {
```

Becomes

```
gulp.task('copy', gulp.series('sass-min'), function() {
```

`gulp.parallel` can also be used to execute the tasks in parallel

Answer (score 18):

I had this exact problem with Gulp and it turns out that you must do away with tasks like that.

You must define your tasks as simple functions and then use your functions to define a task with `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel()`.

I don't use this on Angular, but here's my gulpfile:

```
const bsync = require('browser-sync');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

function sync(done) {
    bsync.init({
        files: [
            '*.html',
            'assets/css/**/*.css',
            'assets/js/**/*.js'
        ],
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        server: './',
        port: 8080,
        reloadDelay: 1000,
        ghostMode: false,
        notify: false
    });
    done();
}

function styles() {
    return gulp.src('./assets/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ remove: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
        .pipe(bsync.stream());
}

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', styles);
}

gulp.task('start', gulp.series(sync, styles, watchFiles));
```

I've got inspired by this [example](https://gist.github.com/jeromecoupe/0b807b0c1050647eb340360902c3203a). Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, super simple thank you!